# Controlling data in a new window from parent

Tags: java, html

I am wanting to open a window using window open() but with a generic calibration image

But then hotswap at will from a gallery on the parent page

I'm very rusty and can't think of how to work it

I can't make any thing more than more/ new windows appear no control happens of child windows

What I'm trying to make is a dm window and a map screen for a dnd table I'm designing

The idea is the dm can click maps on screen one and they change on screen 2

Once I get that going I will work on making a gallery that generates based on folder contents but first things first

Answer (score 0):

You can assign the result of `window.open` to a variable and interact with it, example below (Doesn't work in Stackoverflow code snippet because `allow-popups` permission is disabled):

```html
<button id="open">Open new window</button>
<button id="change">Change content</button>
<script>
  let w;
  document.getElementById('open').addEventListener('click', () => {
    w = window.open('');
    w.document.body.innerHTML = '<h1>Hello</h1>';
  });
  document.getElementById('change').addEventListener('click', () => {
    w.document.body.innerHTML = `<h1>${Date.now()}</h1>`;
  });
</script>
```

Comment: I might be  being Daft but how would i make that code display an image in the new window and how would i make the new window frameless etc